# How to set Background Image in Mvc5 in View

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I am working on MVC5 project I want to set background Image in the Index.cshtml view. I tried the following:

```
<body style="background-image: url(pexels-photo-955470.jpeg)">
```

and

```
    <body style="background-image: url(../../Views/Home/pexels-photo-955470.jpeg)">

</body>
```

These solutions are not working
Note the image path is CleaningShell\CleaningShell.Web\Views\Home

Comment: Try `@Url.Content` with virtual path to target image like this: `<body style="background-image: url('@Url.Content("~/Views/Home/pexels-photo-955470.jpeg")')">`, or use CSS class instead of using `style` attribute.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was hoping to find Answer but nobody gave me the right answer so for these people who looking for an answer,

1_ Click on your solution  > Add a new folder and named it Image.
2_ Go to your Solution path and copy the image you want into the image folder.
3_back to your solution > right click on the image folder > choose to add an existing folder and then choose the image you copied in your image folder inside the solution folder.

in your code

background-image: url(../../Images/pexels-photo-982047.jpeg)

This solution works for me you may find an easy way to do it.

Answer (score 1):

To add background image in a view (.cshtml page in Asp.net MVC), you simply need to add it in < body > tag as 'background-image' attribute.

Best way to set background image is this i think, with css:

```
body {
background-image: url('your_img_path');
margin: 0;
}
```